# Remove substring parent within pandas group

Tags: python, performance, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got a pandas dataframe structured like:

```
col1  col2 
A     C1.123
A     C1.123.89
B     D0.3
B     E98
```

*col2* represents tree structured data, where for example `C1.123.89` is a child node of `C1.123`. Note that the *col2* entries can be up to 11 levels deep, e.g. D09.123.908.90.12.123.982.321.23.12

A small dataset can be found [here](https://osf.io/tbdmr/).

I'd like to "squash" the dataframe above so that each *col1* group contains only the deepest nodes (the parents are removed). So, I expect the output

```
col1  col2 
A     C1.123.89
B     D0.3
B     E98
```

So far I'm tackling it like

```
def has_children(df, col):
    all_vals = df[col].tolist()
    return df[col].map(lambda x: any([x+'.' in l for l in all_vals]))

for col1, group in merge.groupby('col1'):
    merge.loc[merge.col1==col1,'has_children'] = has_children(group, 'col2')
```

My *back-of-the-envelope* calculations show this should take about 6hrs to run with my million or so rows. Is there a more efficient approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

Without the full tree-levels of the data set, I'm not sure if this is faster. It essentially just looks at which substrings are only subsets with themselves for each separate value in `col1`.

```
def g(x):
    split_lists =[set(x.split('.')) for x in x]
    keep_list = []
    for i in range(len(split_lists)):
        keep = [split_lists[i].issubset(item) for item in split_lists]
        only_one = sum(keep) == 1
        keep_list.append(only_one)
    return keep_list

df[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(g)]
```